# Count by ID if value is lower than and set the value 1

Tags: sql

I have a problem.
My table is **tableXYZ**
I have a row **a** where i set the year.
I have a row **b** where i need to set value 1 if the year from row **a** is lower than 2019 and 0 if is > 2019.

After all i need to make a count from row **b** only the 1 values as total.

How can i do that, because i tried a lot of examples but doesn't work.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: _because i tried a lot of examples but doesn't work_ then please post a query have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS [b_count]
FROM (
    -- Use case to evaluate column a and set value for column b
    SELECT a,
    CASE WHEN a < 2019 then '1' else '0' end as [b]
    FROM tableXYZ
) AS X -- Alias of subquery
WHERE X.b = '1' -- Select only rows where b = '1'
```